# Pytorch on Windows : Dataloader problems with numworkers

Tags: windows-10, pytorch

I have just got a new computer running Windows 10 which has a GPU so I wanted to see if I could sensibly use it for machine learning.
So I tried running an old model which I previously trained on Google Colab.
The answer is that it does do quite well, but I discovered that I could not use more than one worker in the Dataloader. Googling found that this is a known issue with PyTorch on Windows in Jupyter Notebooks so I tried running it in a normal Python program. I found that it did work but that the creation of the DataIterator took a very long time. Below are the times in seconds for 1, 2 and 6 workers, each done twice:

[image]

I note that 2 workers seems to be the fastest and there seems to be quite a lot of variation which surprised me as the machine was doing nothing else.

So the first question is:

- Is there a way to let PyTorch choose the most efficient number of workers to use?

The second question is:

- If I install a version of Linux will I be able to use Jupyter Notebooks with multiple workers which is what I would prefer to do in an ideal world.

The code I ran is below the relevant part is after `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset,DataLoader

import os
import numpy as np
#import gym
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
    expansion = 1

    def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_planes, planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes, kernel_size=3,
                               stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)

        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or in_planes != self.expansion*planes:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_planes, self.expansion*planes,
                          kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.expansion*planes)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.bn2(self.conv2(out))
        out += self.shortcut(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out

# create dataset
class C4Dataset(Dataset):
    '''
        the data for the first 12moves is held in a pickles list
        as (key,val)
        The key has to be converted to the pos amd mask which can then be converted to the ones,twos and zeros
        Val is the value for the player playing so needs to be changed for wnen moves  i odd to minus val
    '''
   
    fileName = r'C:\Users\alan\Desktop\Python\Python36\connect4\Layers\ListAllKeyVal19'
    bottom_mask = 4432676798593    
    board_mask  = bottom_mask * ((1 << 6) - 1)
    bNos = 2**np.arange(49, dtype = np.uint64)
    
    def getData(fileName):
        with open(fileName,'rb') as inFile:
            dict = pickle.load(inFile)
        return dict
    
    def oneHot(x):
        return np.eye(37,dtype = np.float32)[x]
        
    def getNoMoves(ones,twos) :
        return np.sum(ones+twos)
    
    def getPosMask(key):
        
        binary = ('{:049b}'.format(key))[::-1]    
        arr    = np.frombuffer(binary.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict'),'u1') - ord('0')
        outArr = np.reshape(arr,(7,7),order = 'F')
        
        arr = np.flipud(outArr)
        pos = arr.copy()
        mask =arr.copy()
        
        for col in range(7):            
            res = np.where(arr[:,col]==1)              
            topPos = res[0][0]
            pos[topPos,col]  = 0
            mask[topPos,col] = 0
            if topPos<6:
                mask[topPos+1:,col] = 1 
        
        msk = np.flipud(mask)
        msk = np.reshape(msk,(49),order = 'F')       
        maskNo  = np.array(msk.dot(C4Dataset.bNos),dtype = np.uint64).item()
       

        return pos.astype('float32'),(pos ^ mask).astype('float32'),(np.logical_not(mask)).astype('float32'),maskNo

    def possible(mask) :
        poss = (mask + C4Dataset.bottom_mask) & C4Dataset.board_mask
        binary = ('{:049b}'.format(poss))[::-1]    
        arr    = np.frombuffer(binary.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict'),'u1') - ord('0')
        outArr = np.reshape(arr,(7,7),order = 'F')
         
        arr = np.flipud(outArr)
         
        return arr

    

    def __init__(self):        
        self.lst = C4Dataset.getData(C4Dataset.fileName)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.lst)

    def __getitem__(self, idx): 
        key,val = self.lst[idx]
        val = int(val)
        ones,twos,zeros,mask = C4Dataset.getPosMask(key)
        
        arr = np.zeros((5,7,7),dtype = np.float32)
        arr[0,:6,:7] = ones[1:,:]
        arr[1,:6,:7] = twos[1:,:]
        arr[2,:6,:7] = zeros[1:,:]
         
        moves = int(C4Dataset.getNoMoves(ones,twos))

        p = (moves % 2) + 3
        
        arr[p,:6,:7] = C4Dataset.possible(mask)[1:,:]
        
               
        return arr,val+18 #C4Dataset.oneHot(val+18)


class C4Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inFilters,outFilters):
        super(C4Net, self).__init__()        

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(inFilters, 32, kernel_size=3,
                               stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.layer1 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer2 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer3 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer4 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer5 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer6 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer7 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        self.layer8 = BasicBlock(32,32)
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(32*7*7,outFilters)#1568

    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.layer1(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = self.layer4(out)
        out = self.layer5(out)
        out = self.layer6(out)
        out = self.layer7(out)
        out = self.layer8(out)
   
        #out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 2)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out


# show some images
def show(img):
    npimg = img.numpy()[:3,:,:]
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1,2,0)), interpolation='nearest')
# get some random training images
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    
    dirName =r'C:\Users\alan\Desktop\Python\Python36\connect4\Layers'
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    # Assuming that we are on a CUDA machine, this should print a CUDA device:

    print(device)
    # create dataloader
    max_epochs = 1
    batchSize = 1024#512#256
    learningRate = .00003
    # Parameters
    params = {'batch_size': batchSize,'shuffle': True,'num_workers': 2}
    # Generators
    dataset = C4Dataset()
    start = time.time()
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, **params)
    middle = time.time()
    
    print('create dataloader',middle-start)
    
    
    dataiter = iter(dataloader)
    end = time.time()
    print('create data iterator',end-middle)
    
    images, labels = dataiter.next()
    final = time.time()
    print('get one batch',final-end)
    # show images
    show(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images[:16]))

    #create the weights
    wts =np.array([59, 963, 12406, 148920, 62551, 47281, 55136, 54312, 44465, 31688,
          27912, 37907, 114778, 242800, 394530, 495237, 582174, 163370, 480850,
          201152, 690905, 633937, 721340, 372479, 193375, 84648, 76576, 91087, 130428,
          154184, 157339, 156453, 227696, 1705325, 548155, 44315, 2082],dtype = np.float32)
    
    maxwt = wts.max()
    weights = wts/maxwt
    weights = torch.from_numpy(weights)
    weights.to(device)
    
    # create the network
    
    net = C4Net(5,37)
    net.to(device)
    PATH = r'C:\Users\alan\Desktop\Python\connectX\c4Net37Weights00003.pth'
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH,map_location=torch.device(device)))
    
    #create the loss function and optimiser
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight = weights.to(device) )
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learningRate)
    
    #train the network
    import time
    start = time.time()
    for epoch in range(max_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)
    
            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
    
            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    
            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0
                torch.save(net.state_dict(),r'C:\Users\alan\Desktop\Python\connectX\tempWeights')
    print('Finished Training')
    # save the weights
    PATH = r'C:\Users\alan\Desktop\Python\connectX\c4Net37Weights00004.pth'
    
    torch.save(net.state_dict(), PATH)
    end = time.time()
    print('elapsed time',end-start)
```

PS the machine is a Dell XPS 17 with Intel Core i9-10885H with 8 cores and the GPU is a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 with Max-Q. In this one test it runs 4 times faster than on Google Colab but I do not know what GPU I was allocated.